# How to use regex lookahead to limit the total length of input string

Tags: regex, expression, limit, regex-lookarounds

I have this regular expression and want to add the rule which limit the total length is no more than 15 chars. I saw some lookahead examples but they're not quite clear. Can you help me to modify this expression to support the new rule.

```
^([A-Z]+( )*[A-Z]+)+$
```

Answer (score 13):

Since you mentioned it in the title, a negative lookahead for your case would be:

```
^(?!.{16,})(regex goes here)+$
```

Note the negative lookahead at the beginning `(?!.{16,})` , that checks that the string does not have 16 or more characters.

However, as @TimPietzcker has pointed out your Regex can be simplified a lot, and re-written in such a form that is not prone to backtracking, so you should use his solution.

Comment: This is still horribly prone to catastrophic backtracking. Not a good regex.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, all this can be simplified a lot:

```
^[A-Z][A-Z ]{0,13}[A-Z]$
```

does exactly what you want. Or at least what your current regex does (plus the length restriction). This especially avoids problems with [catastrophic backtrackin](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)g which you're setting yourself up for when nesting quantifiers like that.

Case in point:

Try the string `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP` against your original regex. The regex engine will match that instantly. Now try the string `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPa`. It will take the regex engine nearly *230,000* steps to figure out it can't match the string. And each additional character doubles the number of steps needed to determine a failed match.

Comment: His looks like it requires at least 2 letters, one at the beginning, one at the end.

Comment: The regexp you gave matches "A" and "A ", neither of which are matched by the poster's regexp.

Comment: No, this one will allow the string ending with white space.

Comment: Maybe `^[A-Z][A-Z ]{0,13}[A-Z]$`

Answer (score 9):

```
^(?=.{15}$)([A-Z]+( )*[A-Z]+)+$
```

[**See it**](http://rubular.com/r/s08MRdPoa9)

Comment: This one enable easily add minimal string length restriction