# Regex to only allow 15 digits length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using below code for regular expression handling but i need to handle only(accepting) 15 digits

```js
([0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{4}([a-zA-Z]{1}|[0-9]{1}).[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){3})
```

This code working fine as per logic but not control only 15 digits
Please help me how to control it?

Comment: How you looked at theese ?
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197549/regular-expression-limit-string-size
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246482/how-to-use-regex-lookahead-to-limit-the-total-length-of-input-string

Comment: Not working (/^(?=.{1,15}$)[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{4}([a-zA-Z]{1}|[0-9]{1}).[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){3})

Comment: Why don't you just use this regex and then check if the string.length is <= 15?

Comment: Because i need one line validation

Answer (score 0):

This controls the regex to 15 digits. you can change it to `{0, 15}` to specify the minimum and maximum digits allowed

```
(?=.{15}$)(([0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{4}([a-zA-Z]{1}|[0-9]{1}).[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){3}))
```

Answer (score 0):

This website can help you out with learning regex: https://regex101.com/ 
It allows you to build, test and understand your regular expressions.

As an example, here's the quick reference for quantifiers:
[image]